# Display Post Author Link above the loop

Tags: loop, author

I am trying to display current post author link above the loop (before loop starts) with this tag `the_author_posts_link()` but it's not displaying the author post link. Anyone please help me.

Edited question:

So I want author post links like this

September 17th, 2008 by (here will be author name with post link)

Like

September 17th, 2008 by Jatin Soni

This is the author meta I belive

Comment: use `get_author_posts_url($id)` instead..

Comment: It's not working. May be I explained wrong but please check my edited question

Comment: that is post date right ?

Comment: Yes that's right I am trying to display post meta above the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It make use of global variable `$post` to get author id of current post. Using that this function returns the author url.

> #### Note -
>
> Make sure you put this in condition ( `is_single()` ) so it only print author url on `single.php`.

```
<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $post->post_author ); ?>
```

#### Update -

```
<?php $username = get_userdata( $post->post_author ); ?>    
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $post->post_author ); ?>"><?php echo $username->user_nicename; ?></a>
```

<sup>This will work, but I'll update my answer if I found more efficient method.</sup>

Comment: Its echo the actual url but I want the author name with its post link (archive) please check my edited question.

Comment: I've updated answer, I'll update again if found more efficient method.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot Amit and Happy Janmashtami. Jai Shri Krishna :)

Answer (score 1):

> You have to use the function in the loop.

Else it won't output anything.

---

#### Edit

First, you might want to retrieve a list of links to all authors.

#### All authors:

You can use [`wp_list_authors()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.1/wp-includes/author-template.php#L268) for this:

```
$authors = wp_list_authors( array(
     'echo'       => false
    ,'feed_image' => false
    ,'feed'       => true
) );
// do something with ...
// $authors;
```

This leaves you with a list of all authors and is similar to what @amit wrote.

#### A single author link

This **is similar to what @amit wrote**.

Setup the user data with [`setup_userdata( $author_id );`](http://queryposts.com/function/setup_userdata/). The `$author_id` can be retrieved with the `$post` global like this:

```
global $post;
$author = setup_userdata( $post->post_author );
echo get_author_posts_url( $post->post_author, $author->user_nicename );
```

Comment: I know that but I want to display post author info above the loop for some reason. How can I do that?

Comment: See update. @amit and me answered at pretty much the same time, so please mark his answer as solution (still appreciate an upvote).

Comment: This is giving url but I want author display name with link. Like September 17th, 2008 by [Jatin Soni](http://mysite.ocm/author/)

Comment: Amit's edited answer works but I really appreciate your help and effort so up voted :) thanks again

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
   $author_id=$authors_post->post_author;
   $author_name = get_userdata($author_id)- >display_name; 
  ?>
   <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(    get_the_author_meta( $author_id ) ); ?>"><?php.    echo $author_name; ?></a>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code and how it works. Dumping of code as an answer is not recognized as an answer.